# Get Windows Disk Storage on Android Programatically

Tags: java, android, rest, localhost, restful-architecture

I would like to create an android app to get the windows disk storage details using Rest service i.e., by connecting android device to system's localhost.

Usually we use File.listRoots() to get the details of windows root path and then storage details by using getTotalSpace() and all (using Java, Tomcat server and jersey on system)

I am looking for a solution to get those details on android.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying getting the 'Windows Disk Storage'?

Comment: Step #1: Create the Windows Web service that serves that data. This has nothing to do with Android. Step #2: Consume that Web service from Android. The details of how to do that will vary based on the type of Web service API that you use (REST, GraphQL, gRPC, etc.).

Comment: @Aris It's windows Disk space like memory space occupied by different partitions C:/, D:/ etc.,

Comment: As mentioned above, create you endpoint that will serve you this and then hit it with your Android App.

Furthermore, I would suggest to avoid using the File class to extract this information. 

Ideally, you could use Files that was introduced in Java7. This implementation can give you easier and more control over you filesystem.

Comment: @Aris you are suggesting me not to use this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html? Could you just give me a reference to Files?

Comment: Knock yourself out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html